# NoClassDefFoundError for MongoClient in cloud9

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, cloud9

I'm using maven to create a jar that i can launch.

So i do : `mvn clean install` and i get the jar.

When i do : `java -jar target/ProjetMRS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` i got this error below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient                                                       
        at iut.nantes.Projet.service.ServicePersonne.<init>(ServicePersonne.java:21)                                                  
        at iut.nantes.projetMRS.Api.<clinit>(Api.java:21)                                                                                
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoClient                                                                     
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)                                                                    
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)                                                                         
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)                                                                 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)                                                                         
        ... 2 more
```

And when i look at the file all import are up-to-date :

```
package iut.nantes.projetMRS.service;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia;
import org.mongodb.morphia.query.Query;
import org.mongodb.morphia.query.UpdateOperations;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import iut.nantes.projetMRS.entity.EntityPersonne;

public class ServicePersonne {
    /*Error here ==>*/ MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017); //connect to mongodb
[...]
```

And the last thing that's very strange is that when i launch my application on my own computer, every thing works fine, i got 0 error and MongoClient is found.

I've looked here : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045681/how-do-i-fix-a-noclassdeffounderror-for-mongoclient-in-my-sparkjava-app` but nobody answered him

I've found some answer but none of them worked for my case.

Below i show you my pom file with all dependencies up-to-date too :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>iut.nantes</groupId>
    <artifactId>projetMRS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>projetMRS</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>iut.nantes.projetMRS.Api</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
            <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the necessary MongoDB classes are being included in the jar? You can confirm by opening the jar in vim and searching for "com/mongodb/MongoClient".

If it isn't included, you can try the maven [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create a fat jar and re-run the command.

I'm not sure where Spark is coming into this picture. But if you're gonna use spark-submit eventually, you'll definitely need a fat jar.

Comment: It's working fine with the maven assembly plugin, thanks you !